# stopwatch is not working

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, web-applications

i have create a web service using visual studio 2010, the web service receives 2 integers and the stopwach, one of the parameter also includes and out statement just as show in the nex example:

```
 public double[][] Parameters(int N_ele, int N_carac, Stopwatch inic, out Stopwatch ini_final)
```

wen i create a web aplication in visual studio a have to create a web reference in order to call the web service. When i call the web service i used the next code:

```
webclient.Serv1 service = new webclient.Serv1();
int element, caracteristic;
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch time_sent = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch time_respond = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
servicie.Parameters(ele, caract,time_sent, out time_respond);
```

how ever visual studio marks and error it says: cannot convert System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch to Application1.webclient.Serv1.Stopwatch

and also the same error in the out statement, if some can help me to find the reason of the error and how to solve it. also i am using the C#, visual studio, .NET framework 4 and 3, using two different web application.

Comment: There seems to be another class with the name `StopWatch` in this namespace: `Application1.webclient.Serv1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dealing with two classes that are both named `Stopwatch`.  One is in the `System.Diagnostics` namespace, and the other is in the `Application1.webclient.Serv1` namespace.  Make sure that all of your `Stopwatch` instances are the same type of `Stopwatch`.

Comment: i change the web service to recive: public double[][] Parameters(int N_ele, int N_carac, System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch inic, out System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch ini_final)  and i still have the same error

Comment: @JUAN That's because the method doesn't use the `System.Diagnostics` version, it uses the other one.  You need to create an instance of *that* type and pass it in.

Comment: you are right i have change this lines: webclient.Stopwacht time_sent = new webclient.Stopwacht();     webclient.Stopwacht time_respond = new webclient.Stopwacht(); insted of using a System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch time_sent = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch time_respond = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You cannot do that.

Long answer:

Referencing a web service in a VS project creates proxy classes for any class declared by the web service.

This means that if you expose the class System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch in a WS parameter, the client reference will create a local proxy class for Stopwatch, in your case Application1.webclient.Serv1.Stopwatch.

Therefore, you cannot pass a System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch on the client side where the server side declares the Stopwatch class.

I would be surprised if this proxy class contains more than just the public data members.

Comment: i have try this same program only using the notepad whit the extention .asmx and .aspx and never recive the error for the stopwatch, the only thing i do is move the program to visual studio